# asp.net dropdownlist onchange using jquery for the rendered html

Tags: jquery, redirect, drop-down-menu, onchange

```
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" 
DataSourceID="spdatasource1" DataValueField="CategoryName" 
AutoPostBack="false">
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

this asp.net dropdonwlist control renders following html. it is databound to a sharepoint list. the dropdown option is being dynamically populated. I am trying to manipulate onselect of an option to redirect to some link like this: It does get redirected to the site but it always passes the first option value. If I selecte Cancer it would still be http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx?cat=Select Category.. WHY??

```
<select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$DropDownList1" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1">
        <option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>
        <option value="All Categories">All Categories</option>
        <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
        <option value="Health Lecture">Health Lecture</option>
        <option value="Heart Health">Heart Health</option>
</select>
```

Jquery used to grab the option and pass to the url:

```
var selectedOption = $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1 option:selected").val();

            $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1").change(function(e) {
                  window.location.href = 'http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx?cat=' + selectedOption
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the value of `selectedOption` before the block that binds your function to the change event of your select dropdown.

At the time the code runs. the value of `$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1 option:selected").val()` is "Selected Category".  That value is then used in your function.

Your function needs to get the value from the object at the time the object is changed, by using `$(this)` to get a reference to the object within the function.

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1").change(function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx?cat=' + $(this).val();
    });
```